# Cronjob every week every hour

Tags: cron

I want to run cron job every hour on every week. For example. On Every Monday i want to run cron function every hour. Is it possible by single command? if yes than what is the cron expression for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 * * * 1 /usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

You can use some of the tools available on the net to manage it easily. 
For example https://crontab-generator.org/

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. But this will run at minute 1 on Monday. I want to run cron job every hour on monday.

Comment: This will run it 1 minute of every hour on Monday